# Двойное условие в t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

подскажите плз какой правильный синтаксис 2-го условия в  t-sql.
Нужно например

```
if ((условие 1 ) или (условие 2 ) ) 
Begin 
end
```

вот мой код:

```
Create trigger mytrigger
    on Report 
    for Update, Insert
    as
        if  Update(salary) or  Insert(salary)
        BEGIN

            if exists 
                (Select * from inserted  i 
                join deleted  d
                on
                i.ReportID=d.ReportID
                where i.salary>d.salary
                or
                i.salary<1000
                )
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('маленькая зп ',1,2)  
                ROLLBACK TRAN
            END
        END
```

пробовал еще  так `if  Update(salary) ,  Insert(salary)`
Ни то, ни другое не работает. Помогите

Comment: OR и еще 11 символов.

Comment: @Pavel, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187326.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) с Вами не согласен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синтаксис у вас правильный:

```
if (условие 1) OR (условие 2)
begin 
end
```

Однако функции триггера `INSERT(colunm)` не существует. Вообще, в данном случае `OR` не нужен. Функция триггера [`UPDATE(column)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) срабатывает и при `insert` и при `update`.

```
create trigger mytrigger
on Report
for Update, Insert
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    if Update(salary)
    BEGIN
        print('do something');
    END;
end
```

Comment: *ясно, спасибо!